# Distinguish between "to quote" and "to cite" in Spanish

Tags: solicitud-de-término, polisemia, desambiguación

I just came across [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/35988) at French.SE and realized that Spanish has a similar "problem": we use the verb [*citar*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9MMVfes) both for quoting someone and for citing some work.

The answer to the linked question shows that in French this is solved by using *faire une citation* (to make a quote) instead of the actual verb *citer* (to quote). But in Spanish we don't say ***hacer una cita***, do we?

Comment: No veo ningún problema con esa palabra, normalmente se entenderá por el contexto y si no puede usarse algún sinónimo como *mencionar*. O a lo mejor no he entendido bien la pregunta

Comment: I've been thinking about this too lately.  I don't think "hacer una cita" works.  How about ***dar la cita*** *[de una obra relacionada]*?  Is that a workaround?

Comment: "hacer una cita" no funciona, pero "citar" si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hacer una cita" could be understood to mean *to make an appointment or assignation*.  I suppose in the right context it wouldn't be misunderstood.  However, in general, I'd suggest:

- Dar/incluir una/la cita/referencia
- Documentar con una cita/referencia

Answer (score 7):

En español yo diría que cuando haces mención de un texto, eso es una cita:

> **[cita](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9MCUXnT)**
>
> 3. f. Nota de ley, doctrina, autoridad o cualquier otro texto que se alega para prueba de lo que se dice o refiere.

Ahora bien, una vez citado el texto conviene especificar de dónde proviene el original, que se hace mediante una referencia:

> **[referencia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Vc9rHUF)**
>
> 5. f. En un escrito, indicación del lugar de él mismo o de otro al que se remite al lector.

Luego entiendo que cuando en las respuestas inserto cosas como la siguiente entiendo que el texto en cursiva es la *cita* (el texto copiado) y el texto en redonda es la *referencia* (el lugar donde puedo encontrar el texto original):

> *En un lugar de la Mancha de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor.*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha", 1605 (España).

Otra cosa es si hablamos de verbos. En ese caso sí que se usa, al parecer, el verbo *citar*:

> **[citar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9MMVfes)**
>
> 2. tr. Referir, anotar o mencionar un autor, un texto, un lugar, etc., que se alega en lo que se dice o escribe.

Nótese que en la definición se habla tanto de *referir* (para la referencia) como de *mencionar* (para la mención o cita). De aquí entiendo que para citar correctamente un texto se debe incluir tanto la cita en sí como la referencia.

Comment: ¿*Dar la referencia*, entonces?

Comment: En inglés también son "references".